# Change time in timepicker when date is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have the following jQuery date and time pickers:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    'minTime': '05:15',
    'maxTime': '21:15',
    'timeFormat': 'H:i',
    'step': 15,
    'forceRoundTime': true,
});

$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
});
```

I want to change the time whenever the date is changed. I have tried the following different methods:

```
$('.datepicker').change(function() {
    $('.timepicker').text('09:15')
})
```

```
$('.datepicker').change(function() {
    $('.timepicker').setTime('09:15')
})
```

```
$('.timepicker').val('09:15')
```

And it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which date and time picker controls are you using? I'm sure if you check their documentations there will be a 'change' event on the datepicker you can hook to, and similarly an 'update' method you can use to set the timepicker

Comment: Bootstrap timepicker and jquery timepicker

Comment: There are *dozens* of those. Please be specific and post links.

Comment: https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery

Comment: Use the `setTime()` method

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Have you debugged this to check that the `change` event is firing as you expect it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using the wrong events/methods for your plugins.  Plain HTML inputs do fine with `change` and `.val()`, but plugins often layer their own functionality on top of that.  You should always use the API exposed by the plugins you're using rather than try to get at the underlying functionality directly.

For `.datetimepicker()` are you using [this library](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)?  If so, then the event you're looking for is `dp.change`:

```
$('.datepicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
    // respond to the change event here
});
```

And for [the time picker you're using](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery), the method is `.setTime()`.  From their documentation in the link you provided:

```
$('#setTimeExample').timepicker('setTime', new Date());
```

The documentation linked doesn't readily identify if you can use a string to set the time as well, but you can certainly try:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker('setTime', '09:15');
```

You can also look for additional documentation and examples for that plugin.

But basically when you're using complex plugins which overlay functionality on top of plain HTML elements, use the APIs provided by those plugins.  You may very well be changing the value of the underlying HTML element, but the plugin might not notice that change if you're circumventing its API.